# Handling multiple row input in jinja template with flask python

Tags: python, forms, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to take in multiple inputs (rows) for a dynamically generated form with Flask python Jinja. My question is what jinja do I need to code to be able to take in the inputs for each row? Any suggestions/guidance/examples appreciated. Thx

Here is the web form: [web form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7mLd.png)

Here is the Jinja template: [Jinja template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIGTM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a unique name to each input to identify each input.

The name attribute is used to reference elements in JavaScript, or to reference form data after a form is submitted.

**Note:** Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form.